# Use the same instance through out the code javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Class Life {
   constructor(name = 'no name') {
     this.name = name;
   }
   getName() {
     return this.name;
   }
   setName(name = 'no name') {
     this.name = name;
   }
}

const MyLife = new Life();
export { getName, setName } = MyLife;
export default MyLife;
```

How can I use the same instance of `new Life()` i.e, `MyLife` throughout my code?

Things I have tried;

```
const MyLife = new Life();
export const getName = MyLife.getName.bind(MyLife);
export const setName = MyLife.setName.bind(MyLife);
export default MyLife;
```

Every time I try to use this in another file i.e, `myOther.js`

import { setName } from '../path-of-class.js`
   setName('Luke Skywalker'); // I get undefined.

What am I doing wrong here?

P.S: the class is in another library, I compile it with webpack & then use in another `<package>`, The class above works fine if used locally within the same `<package>` but when I try to use from `<package-a>` to `<package-b`> I get `setName` of undefined.

Comment: Idk for sure if there is a difference but have you tried `export default new Life();` instead of all bindings and then importing `ìmport life from '../Life';`

Comment: I want to be able use `getName` & `setName` of the same instance from one place.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving your instance of Life into a static variable probably near the class and return it with a static method

```js
class Life {
   static getInstance() {
     if (!Life.instance) {
       Life.instance = new Life();
     }
     return Life.instance;

   }
   constructor(name = 'no name') {
     this.name = name;
   }
   getName() {
     return this.name;
   }
   setName(name = 'no name') {
     this.name = name;
   }
}

Life.instance = null;

export default Life;
```

in another file:

```js
import Life from 'module';
const myLife = Life.getInstance();
```

I'm not completely certain how webpack handles the imports. But having a single instance of a class and using it everywhere is a common pattern in object oriented programming (lookup singleton), usually solved by attaching a static variable of the instance to a class and getting it with a static method. This example achieves the same thing by having a static `instance` and using `getInstance()` to return it or create one if it wasn't already. This is a classic implementation of this pattern.

Comment: Can you please explain your code a bit more, as to how it solved the problem & what it is trying to achieve here. =)